# Readygraph Plugin is deleted from wordpress but Scripts are still loading and tracking

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog [tectrick.org](http://tectrick.org). I install readygraph plugin for increase subscribers on it. After some time i delete plugin and plugin file ,even from plugins folder. But scripts are still running on my blog. These scripts are not shown in view page source. But shown in page speed insight test.

How to rid off readygraph and other unwanted hidden scripts from wordpress

Comment: Did you wait 30 seconds before refreshing PageSpeed? Also, try checking the page source when you are not logged in.

Comment: @BardiHarborow, it's showing for me in PageSpeed as well.

Answer (score 0):

`http://tectrick.org/wp-content/themes/tectrick/js/theme_functions.js` triggers the loading (on line 34) of `http://www.readygraph.com/scripts/readygraph.js`, which rediects to `https://az759089.vo.msecnd.net/static/scripts/readygraph.v1.0.69.gz.js`.

You will need to remove the JavaScript code from `theme_functions.js`.